# Homeomorphism between $X/\sim$ and an interval

Tags: general-topology

Let be $X=[0,1]  \cup [2,3]$, and $Y=[0,1]$ both with the euclidian topology. Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ such as $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow x=y$ or $\{x,y\}=\{1,2\}$.
Show that $X/\sim $ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

Proof.:

I say $\pi: X/\sim \rightarrow Y, x \mapsto [x]$

Even if not requested I tried to "see" how is the quotient. I think it's a interval from $0$ and  $3$ (both sides included) with the identification of $1$ with $2$.
I also wanted to understan which were the open sets in this topology and i got they are the intervals like $(a,b)$ with $[1] \notin (a,b)$. In fact $\pi^{-1}(a,b)=(a,b) \in \tau$.

But if I take for instance $[1] \in (a,b)$ I got that $\pi^{-1}(a,b)=(a,1] \cup [2,b)$, which doesn't belongs to $\tau$.

Is it all correct ?

But I can't still find an homeomorphism between the quotient set and $Y$.
Could I define this map by cases?

$f:X/\sim \rightarrow Y$, $t\mapsto 2t$ if $t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, $t\mapsto 2t-1$, if $t \in (\frac{1}{2},1]$... but this map is not even continuous...

Any hint?

Comment: Define $f:X/\sim\to Y$ by $f([x]_{\sim})=\frac{x}{2}$ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $f([x]_{\sim})=\frac{x-1}{2}$ otherwise. Obviously $f$ is well defined and bijective. It is enough to show that it is continous to be a homeomorphism because $X/\sim$ is compact (as a Hausdorff quotient of a compact space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following useful result, which I'm sure you know.

**Lemma.** Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Suppose there is a surjective continuous map $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ such that $x\sim y$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$ and such that for each $U\subseteq Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, then $U$ is open in $Y$. Then, there exists an unique continuous map $\varphi:X/_\sim \longrightarrow Y$ which factors $f$ through the natural projection onto the quotient. Moreover, this map is an homeomorphism.

In most situation, you don't need to verify the awkward condition on the open sets of $Y$, as this is immediate if $f$ is open or closed (images of open/closed are open/closed respectively). Another useful corollary is the following.

**Corollary.** Suppose $X$ is a compact topological space and $Y$ is Hausdorff. If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation over $X$ and $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous surjective, then the induced map $\varphi :X/_\sim \longrightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism.

As for your example, you need to define a continuous surjective map $f:[0,1]\cup[2,3]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ which respects the equivalence relation. Since $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff and $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is compact, you don't have to worry about the conditions in Lemma above.

As some others have specified above, the idea is to "move" the first interval to $[0,1/2]$ and the second one to $[1/2,1]$. This is made by the function
$$x\mapsto x/2$$
for the first interval, and $$x\mapsto (x-1)/2$$ for the second one. Check the conditions and you will find your homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks so much ! It's clear now! Anyway, the open sets I found are correct? (Just to know)

Comment: Dear @feddy, in your description of the open sets you are missing a point. Since open sets in $X/_\sim$ are those sets $U$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, you have correctly all those open sets $U\subseteq [0,3]$ not containing $[1]=[2]$, but if $(a,b)$ is such that $a<1<2<b$ you have still an open set, since $\pi^{-1}(a,b)=(a,1]\cup [2,b)=(a,b)\cap X$ and this is open in the subset topology of the Euclidean topology! The same if $1<a<2<b$ or $a<1<b<2$.

Answer (score 3):

Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&X/\sim&\longrightarrow&[0,1]\\&[x]&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\frac x2&\text{ if }x\in[0,1)\\\frac{x-1}2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.